# Prove $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ 2a&2b\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} c\\2c \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Prove that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 2a & 2b \\ \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} c \\ 2c \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
has solution
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{c}{a} \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
+t
\begin{pmatrix} -b \\ a \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
and $t$ is real number.

If I plug some numbers, all $y$ variables are vanish and the matrix has **infinitely many solutions**, but I have no idea how the solution could be into like that. Also I haven't reached Vector chapter.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean to ask why the solution is that or why there are infinitely many?

Comment: @ChristopherLiu I asked why the solution is that. I can't make good words to the question so feel free to edit my question.

Comment: did you solve it and reached a solution ? if so what what the presentation of the solution you have reached ?

Comment: @d_e The solution is formula. I tried to plug in all values, solved it with standard elimination method and all $y$ variables are vanished. I don't know how to prove the formula.

Comment: What if $a=0$?.

Comment: notice , there is mistake ... if you plug $t=0$ you get $x= - \frac ca$, $y = 0$, which does *not* solve the matrix! ($+ \frac ca$ would solve it)

Comment: @d_e Ah, typo. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast approach, as I see it is (in case $a \neq 0$):
you have $ax+by = c$ , just plug in $y=0+ta$, and you get 
$$ax + bta = c$$
$$x= \frac ca - bt$$.

alternatively, in case you don't have the solution in advance, use same approach and you will get: $$ x = \frac ca - \frac ba y$$, so the general solution will be $$(x,y) = (\frac ca - \frac bat , t)$$ 
$$ (x,y) = (\frac ca, 0) + (-\frac ba,1)t$$ where $t$ is free. if you plug $t=a$ you will end up with the same result.

Comment: So, using $t$ here is redundant?

Comment: I've edited my answer, I should have you $t$ ,, $y$ is somewhat confusing.

Comment: So $
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{c}{a} \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}+t
\begin{pmatrix} -b \\ a \\ \end{pmatrix}
$ would be same with
$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{c}{a} \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}+t
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-b}{a} \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: yes indeed.the are infinite representations of the solution.but they are all the same. you can see that you have the same solutions.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!